# How to bypass jwt policy within mesh using istio

Tags: istio

I am setting up the end user authentication using istio. I have service A and service B in my mesh and service B is applied the jwt policy so that for requests out the cluster will need the authorization token to access.

However, I found if service A need to access service B, it also returns 401 means need the token, how I can bypass the authentication within the mesh and apply it only for traffic out of the mesh?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is feasible to arrange access to the same K8s target service with different authentication approaches, assuming that external mesh visitors are entitling with [JWT](https://jwt.io/) token against this service, however internal mesh clients should not respect this policy rule.

Looking deeper into the [Origin authentication](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#authentication) (End-user authentication) [design](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.authentication.v1alpha1/#TargetSelector) aspects you may find that Istio [Policy](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.authentication.v1alpha1/#Policy) strongly relies on the [target](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.authentication.v1alpha1/#TargetSelector) workloads, representing particular K8s service object. Therefore, you can't change JWC policy behavior depending on the way how the initial request reaches the target k8s service.

I would say that you can apply JWT policy on the top `istio-ingressgateway` service level, thus all outward network requests to the mesh services will be authenticated on this stage, besides mesh service-to-service communication discovered by K8s system, that can be secured by [mTLS](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#mutual-tls-authentication) transport channel. But this solution requires to re-consider current microservices design affecting all the entire mesh services authorization and authentication methods.